# What is the syntax error on the line <a> tag? It shows: "> on the web page with image

Tags: php, html, syntax

At the end of the 'a' tag "> symbol directly seen on web page above the image.

```
<?php foreach ($sayisal as $sayi){ ?>
 <div class="row container-grid projects-wrapper">
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 sayisal">
   <div class="gallery-box mt-4">
                                                        
     <a class="gallery-popup" href="<?php echo '<img src="data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($sayi ['resim']).'" height="150" width="500">' ?>" >
      <img class="gallery-demo-img img-fluid mx-auto" <?php echo  '<img src="data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($sayi ['resim']).'" height="150" width="500">' ?>  />
       <div class="gallery-overlay">
          <div class="overlay-content">
            <h5 class="overlay-title"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($sayi['adi']); ?></h5>
                                                                    
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
                                                        
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not put an `<img>` inside the `href` Attribute of an `<a>`-Tag.

Change your Code:

```
<a class="gallery-popup" href="#" >
   <img class="gallery-demo-img img-fluid mx-auto"  />
   <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <div class="overlay-content">
          <h5 class="overlay-title"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($sayi['adi']); ?></h5>                                                                  
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

- Why Do you want an Image inside an href?
- You also had an `<img>`-Tag inside a div-tag, which I removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed it this way, the problem disappeared.

```
<a class="gallery-popup" href="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($soz['resim']) ?>" >
                                                        <img class="gallery-demo-img img-fluid mx-auto" src=" <?php echo 'data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($soz['resim']) ?>"  />
                                                            <div class="gallery-overlay">
                                                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                                                    <h5 class="overlay-title"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($soz['adi']); ?></h5>
                                                                    
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </a>
```